# Enabling both Cookie authentication and ASP.NET Identity authentication in an MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity-3

I have an MVC site with both MVC controllers and WebApi controllers using cookie authentication. However, I'd like some of the WebApi controllers to authenticate using an Identity 3 server. I checked this answer but the property AuthenticationScheme is not available probably because I'm using Identity 3 (or maybe it's part of .NET core, which I'm not currently using).

[How do I issue the corresponding Bearer and Cookie identity in ASP.NET with multiple Authorization schemes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41985478/how-do-i-issue-the-corresponding-bearer-and-cookie-identity-in-asp-net-with-mult)

How could I tell some WebApi controllers to authenticate against an Identity 3 server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, this is possible using the method app.Map and indicating inside it the path and the authentication method. Something like

```
        app.Map("/mobile", idsrvApp =>
        {
            idsrvApp.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
            {
               ...
            });
        });

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
         ...
        });
```